# Return Value from function in gs file to javascript file (HTML)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to return value (idValues) from gs file to javascript file.

GS file

```js
function getMachineDB() {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZI16KqM7Uy_ZDTsTUFYFRSXS-DBkRdigp-3SiIy- 
    CPA/edit#gid=693962232";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Equiplist");      
    var idValues = sheet.getRange(2,4,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    return idValues;
}
```

Javascript file

```
function regExp(machinenoNum){

   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(idValues) {

   var vmachineno = "/(" + idValues.join("|") + ")/";
   return (vmachineno.test(machinenoNum));
   }).getMachineDB();

}

    function isValid() {
    var x = document.getElementById("machineno");
    if (regExp(x.value)) { 
       return true
    } else {
      machineno.setCustomValidity('nomor mesin tidak terdaftar');
      return false
    }
}
```

HTML file

```
<input type="text" id="machineno" class="form-input" name="entry.1002184227" placeholder="xx-xxx-xx" onChange="return isValid()" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required/>
```

These code is comparing value from text box form with some data from Spreadsheet. How to get value  of idValue from GS file to javascript file? thank you

Comment: By `Javascript file` I suppose you mean that you have deployed this Apps Script project as a web app. Is that correct? The code looks ok, you are calling `google.script.run...` etc. This line may produce an error `return (vmachineno.test(machinenoNum));` is that what you have found? This is because `var vmachineno = "/(" + idValues.join("|") + ")/";` just creates a string with no `test()` method. What are you trying to do with the values from the spreadsheet?

Comment: @iansedano I need to compare the variable 'x' (from text box of a form) with values from spreadsheet. If the value isn't available in the spreadsheet, the form can't be submitted

Comment: can you confirm its deployed as a web app and if you are getting any errors?

Comment: @iansedano yes it's deployed as web app, the result is, any value on the text box, whether it is available or not on spreadsheet, it can't be submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Current behavior

To reproduce your behavior, I created a new project to test. I also used the values 1-9 in the spreadsheet for validation.

[image]

When you run the web app currently, it displays this in the console:

[image]

This relates to this code:

```js
function regExp(machinenoNum){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(idValues) {
   var vmachineno = "/(" + idValues.join("|") + ")/";
   return (vmachineno.test(machinenoNum));
   }).getMachineDB();

}
```

If you add some `console.log` to this code:

```js
function regExp(machinenoNum){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(idValues) {
   console.log(idValues)
   var vmachineno = "/(" + idValues.join("|") + ")/";
   console.log(vmachineno)
   return (vmachineno.test(machinenoNum));
   }).getMachineDB();

}
```

You get:

- `idValues` is `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]]`
- `vmachineno` is `"/(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|)/"`

`vmachineno` is just a string, it does not have any method called `test` on it. So this is why you get an error here.

There is also no action attached to not finding the value in the Spreadsheet, so even if the error was resolved, this would still not warn the user about invalid input.

#### Solution

```js
function regExp(machinenoNum){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(idValues) {
        
        // This just converts the `idValues` into simple array of strings.
        const values = idValues.map(val => `${val[0]}`)
  
        // Checking if the values from SS contain the machinenoNum value
        // If this is true, function returns and does nothing.
        if (values.includes(machinenoNum)) return true

        // If the above check is false, then this will make an alert in the browser window.
        alert("invalid input!")
      })
      .getMachineDB();
}
```

So when you enter a value that is in the spreadsheet, nothing will happen. If the value is not in the spreadsheet, then you get this:

[image]

#### EDIT - Walkthrough of code:

- The page is loaded and you have an empty text box

[image]

- The user inserts a value, for example `11` and presses ENTER.
- This causes `onChange="return isValid()"` from the HTML to run.
- `isValid()` will get the value from the text box with `var x = document.getElementById("machineno");`
- Then will use this value here: `if (regExp(x.value)) {`
- So now `regExp` is running.
- This will now get the values from the spreadsheet and test if the `x.value` is contained there.
- If it is not, then it will produce an alert:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. Which code compare `idValues` with value from text box form? For example I declare with `var x = document.getElementById("machineno");`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The function `regExp` is called from `isValid` where it gets the value from the text box. In the `regExp` function, it calls the spreadsheet `google.script...` and when it gets the values it checks to see if it is contained there. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: I dont get it. `isValid` is comparing value from `regExp` function with value form text box. and also define action when value is match or not.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what you mean, I have edited my answer to provide a walk-through of the code, can you look at it and let me know if this makes things clearer? Did you test the code?